# How can I share a struct array between an app and iMessage Extension in Swift 3?

Tags: swift3, emoji, ios-app-group, imessage-extension

I am facing a weird issue when sharing a struct array between an app and iMessage Extension.

Here is my code.

```
struct RecentlyUsed {
    var isPreset: Bool?
    var imgId: Int?
}

extension RecentlyUsed {
    init?(data: NSData) {
        if let coding = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data as Data) as? Encoding {
            isPreset = coding.isPreset! as Bool
            imgId = coding.imgId!
        }
    }
    func encode() -> NSData {
        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: Encoding(self)) as NSData
    }
    private class Encoding: NSObject, NSCoding {
        let isPreset: Bool?
        let imgId: Int?
        init(_ recentlyUsed: RecentlyUsed) {
            self.isPreset = recentlyUsed.isPreset
            self.imgId = recentlyUsed.imgId
        }
        @objc required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            self.isPreset = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "isPreset") as? Bool
            self.imgId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "imgId") as? Int
        }
        @objc func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
            aCoder.encode(isPreset, forKey: "isPreset")
            aCoder.encode(imgId, forKey: "imgId")
        }
    }
}
```

And I created an app group named "group.io.interepid.sharingdata" to share this array and then tested to read and write in my app.

**So it works very well.**

```
var recentlyUsedArr: [RecentlyUsed] = []
...
// Code for read
let settings = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.io.interepid.sharingdata")
        if let dataArray = settings?.object(forKey: "data") as? [NSData] {
            self.recentlyUsedArr.append(contentsOf: dataArray.map{ RecentlyUsed(data: $0)! })
        } else {

        }
// Code for write
let settings = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.io.interepid.sharingdata")
                let placeData = self.recentlyUsedArr.map{ $0.encode() }
                settings?.set(placeData, forKey: "data")
                settings?.synchronize()
```

But when I read the array in this app's iMessage extension, I got an error.

I used the code the same with app's side.

> 2017-02-14 10:02:59.648256 Emoji Me[5616:2399759] * **Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException'**,
>   reason: '* -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode
>   object of class
>   (_TtCV7emojime12RecentlyUsedP33_B90A8EFD4225717A6A5C48CD3F99B2FC8Encoding)
>   **for key (root); the class may be defined in source code or a library
>   that is not linked'**
>   Blockquote
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x18794d1b8 0x18638455c 0x1883f0408 0x1883f05c4 0x1883bc1cc 0x1883bbfa8 0x1883bb168 0x100085ff8
>   0x100076ec0 0x100076f6c 0x100219068 0x100075f2c 0x100078018
>   0x18d802924 0x18d8024ec 0x100074048 0x1000737dc 0x10007383c
>   0x1a34e2edc 0x1867d61fc 0x1867d61bc 0x1867dad68 0x1878fa810
>   0x1878f83fc 0x1878262b8 0x1892da198 0x18d86d7fc 0x18d868534
>   0x186a2bcc8 0x186a2d944 0x1885723c4 0x19001e128 0x19001dc90
>   0x19001e14c 0x1885580d4 0x1868095b8) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

How can I fix the error?